# Setting rChart width and height

Tags: r, knitr, rcharts

In the (few so far) learning-oriented examples on the web of integrating knitr and rCharts we often see a line of code within an R chunk as follows:

```
options(RCHART_WIDTH = 800, RCHART_HEIGHT = 500)
```

When I include this sort of variable setting in an R chunk of an R markdown document it seems to make no difference at all to the actual size of the eventual chart in html.  What extra thing am I missing that will let me control the width and height of rCharts?  Reproducible *.rmd file is below.

````
```{r echo = F, message = F, cache = F}
opts_chunk$set(results = 'asis', comment = NA, message = F, tidy = F, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE)
require(rCharts)
options(RCHART_WIDTH = 600, RCHART_HEIGHT = 400)
```

## Example plot with un-customised dimensions
```{r}
data(economics, package = 'ggplot2')
econ <- transform(economics, date = as.character(date))
m1 <- mPlot(x = 'date', y = c('psavert', 'uempmed'), type = 'Line',
            data = econ)
m1$set(pointSize = 0, lineWidth = 1)
m1$print('chart2', include_assets = TRUE, cdn=TRUE)
```
````

Comment: The issue is that the `print` method does not include the css that sizes the charts. Easiest fix would be to add the following css to your Rmd file `<style>.rChart{width: 600px; height: 400px}</style>`. The `print` method is being rewritten and we are trying to figure out the most flexible yet useful way to do it.

Comment: Thanks @Ramnath, that works fine and the explanation makes sense too.  I'll accept that as an answer if you want to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the print method does not include the css that sizes the charts. Easiest fix would be to add the following css to your Rmd file .rChart{width: 600px; height: 400px}. The print method is being rewritten and we are trying to figure out the most flexible yet useful way to do it.